# React Native Expo - Background Task Manager + Background Fetch

Tags: android, react-native, expo, react-native-background-fetch

I have a react native expo app and one of its features is the timer. I also use 'react-native-background-timer' to have my timer run in the background. However, after like two minutes in the background the app stops working and the timer freezes. It starts again when the app goes to the foreground. Well, I do not want that - i want the timer to be on till the total seconds left are zero.

So, I tried to use expo task manager along with expo background fetch. The thing is that when i try to register the task from task manager I get an error that i need to define task before registration. Well, the task is registered cuz the TaskManager.isTaskDefined returns true.

Maybe some of you have a working example of the expo task manager and bg fetch? I'd like to see it and compare...

The issue exists on ios and android. Currently, im testing the thing on my development build created with eas.